# How to make a button disabled or hidden in settings page while navigating from login page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have got two buttons in the `MainPage`, one is Login button and another Navigate button. When the user click on the Navigate button, it should display Home, Settings and other tabs, but would like to make one of the button in settings page as hidden or disabled ?

I have tried the below code with `MessagingCenter' and received in Settings, but it is not working, could someone please have a look !

//Settings.xaml given below;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="soccerapp.Settings" BackgroundColor="#755f89" Title="Settings">
    <AbsoluteLayout>
        <!-- Normal Page Content -->
        <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1"
             AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
            <Label HeightRequest="50" FontSize="18" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="Please enter today's soccer status-" />

            <Label Text="{Binding SoccerStatus}"></Label>
            <Label Text="{Binding CurrentDate}"></Label>
            <Button x:Name="button1"
              Text="Click here !"
              FontSize="Large"
              VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
              HorizontalOptions="Center"
              Clicked="OnButtonClicked" />
        </StackLayout>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

//MainPage.xaml.cs :

```
public async void NavigateButton_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var tabbedPage = new TabbedPage();
            tabbedPage.Children.Add(new Home("Welcome"+' '+emailEntry.Text+' '+",have a nice day!"));
            tabbedPage.Children.Add(new Settings(soccerAvailability, emailEntry.Text));
            await Navigation.PushAsync(tabbedPage);
            MessagingCenter.Send<object>(this, "TurnOffButton");

        }

 public Settings(string emailText)
        {
            InitializeComponent();           
            emailTextVal = emailText;
            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object>(this, "TurnOffButton", (sender) => 
            {
                button1.IsVisible = false;
            });

        }
```

// login button code follows:

```
public async void Button_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        this.IsBusy = true;
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
        string emailText = emailEntry.Text;
        string passwordText= passwordEntry.Text; 
        if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(emailEntry.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(passwordEntry.Text))
        {

            if(ValidateEmail(emailText) == true)
            {

               int count = (from x in conn.Table<PlayerDetails>().Where(x => x.Email == emailText) select x).Count();
                if (count!= 0)
                {
                    try
                    {
                       List<PlayerDetails> myList = (from x in conn.Table<PlayerDetails>().Where(x => x.Email == emailText && x.Password == passwordText) select x).ToList();
                        if(myList.Count() > 0)
                        {
                                var tabbedPage = new TabbedPage();
                                PlayerDetails playerDetails = new PlayerDetails();
                                SoccerAvailability soccerAvailability = new SoccerAvailability();
                                tabbedPage.Children.Add(new Home(emailEntry.Text));
                                tabbedPage.Children.Add(new Settings(soccerAvailability, emailEntry.Text));
                                await Navigation.PushAsync(tabbedPage);
                                var profilePicTollbarItem = new ToolbarItem()
                                {
                                    Icon = "LF.PNG"
                                };
                                profilePicTollbarItem.Clicked += OnProfilePicClicked;
                                tabbedPage.ToolbarItems.Add(profilePicTollbarItem);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            this.IsBusy = false;
                            await DisplayAlert("Notification", "No such email or password", "Cancel");

                        }

                    }
                    catch (NullReferenceException ex)
                    {
                      if(ex!=null)
                        Debug.WriteLine("Something is thrown ! " + e.ToString());
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        IsBusy = false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                     this.IsBusy = false;
                    await DisplayAlert("Notification", "Unable to find the user details", "Cancel");
                } 
            }
            else
            {
                this.IsBusy = false;
                await DisplayAlert("Notification", "Email is not a valid one", "Cancel");
            }   
        }
        else
        {
            this.IsBusy = false;
            await DisplayAlert("Notification","Input details cannot be blank", "Cancel");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it would be a lot simpler to just pass a `bool` in the constructor of `Settings`

```
public Settings(string emailText, bool ShowButton = false)
{
    ...

    button1.IsVisible = ShowButton;
}
```

then when you create the `Settings` page for your two different code paths pass in the appropriate value

```
// hide button - when called from Navigate
tabbedPage.Children.Add(new Settings(emailEntry.Text, false));

// show button - when called from Login
tabbedPage.Children.Add(new Settings(emailEntry.Text, true));
```

Comment: Jason, I have tried that, now its hidden in both login and navigate mode. But I need, on click on Navigate the button should be hidden and during login process the user should be able to see the button and perform action on that button

Comment: please post the code that shows what happens when you click Login

Comment: I don't see anything in that code that Navigates to settings.  You need to clearly explain the two different workflows and which one triggers the button visibility.  Or is the button visibility triggered by whether or not the user has logged in first?

Comment: In my question, I have given the `NavigateButton_OnClicked(){}` flow/ code that does the Navigation to home and in that mode I don't want to see that button. The other  flow `Button_Clicked(){}`, the login flow where I should see the button.

Comment: but there is nothing in Button_Clicked() that actually navigates to another page?

Comment: I got your point, I have added the full code of `Button_Clicked(){}`, please have a look

Comment: What I suggested should work.  You have two different code paths that create a new Settings page, so you should be able to pass a bool flag that will set the visibility of the button.  If this is not working you should first verify that the bool is actually getting passed with the correct value in the two different cases.

Comment: Yes I have two code path, as suggested I have given two different bool flags, but I how can we give these flags inside the settings constructor for two different flows `public Settings(string emailText, bool ShowButton = false, bool ShowClickHereButton = true)
        {
           InitializeComponent();          
           emailTextVal = emailText;
           BindingContext = status;
           button1.IsVisible = ShowClickHereButton;
           button1.IsVisible = ShowButton;
        }` The above is not working

Comment: You only need ONE bool flag in your constructor.  Code path A passes false, code path B passes true.  See my last edit.